# Controlling access to documents for specific users

Tags: users

I need customers to be able to access certain documents (PDFs mainly) specifically for them (they contain sensitive information).  The document information is setup in nodes.  I have looked at a lot of access control modules, but they all seem to focus on user roles.  I don't want a role for every customer.  What would be the best way to structure this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the Groups module + private file/media setup.

Comment: Again, it seems like you have to set up 1 group for every customer.  We have a lot of customers and this seems like a lot of extra overhead.  All the documents are individualized, although customers could have 5-10 documents.

Answer (score 0):

A possible (but somewhat convoluted) solution could be to use [Node access user reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) module with private files setup. Basically adding a user reference to a node will allow them to see its content (including files) and having files' folder protected will prevent direct access to the file urls.

Comment: This looks like a possibility, I'll check into it.  What do you mean by "somewhat convoluted"?

Comment: well I've personally never done anything like it as we tend to write custom code for things like this. Usually only relying on a contrib module gets you only 90-95% of a solution to a fairly complex problem. So just make sure to test all the edge cases (especially if security is important) to make sure everything is in order.